# Formula to get total number of students from given percentile and rank

Tags: analysis, percentile

I just want to know that how i get total number of student who have given the exam with me if have my rank and percentile of that given exam.

> Formula to get total number of student who appeared in an exam

Let’s suppose a person given an exam and he got rank 44 and percentile 99.81 in that exam then how many student was appear in that exam ?

e.g.

```
Total of student = x
Rank = 44
Percentile = 69.81
Total number of Student = ?
```

I don’t know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 44 students constitute (100 -99.81=0.19) percentage of students. So the total number of students must have been $ 44 \times 100 / 0.19 = 23, 158$.